# How can I make intent inside onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, admob

I want when the player clicks on the imageView the ads should show first if its ready and then go to the next activity
here is my code

```
FalgQuizImageView.setOnClickListener {
    if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
        mInterstitialAd?.show(this)
    }

    mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
        override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
            val intent = Intent(this, QuizQuestionsCar::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError?) {
            val intent = Intent(this, QuizQuestionsCar::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parameter on [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E)) constructor is of type `Context`, you are passing `this` which in your case refers to the `FullScreenContentCallback` object and its not of type `Context`. To fix this do the following

```
val intent = Intent(this@YourActivityName, QuizQuestionsCar::class.java)
```

`this@YourActivityName` refers to your `Activity` object, which is a `Context`

Comment: thanks bro, now intent is work fine but ad still not shown first how can i fix that